# Fetch File to Global Variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch

Is there a better way to fetch a .txt file without having to write it to a hidden paragraph and then reading from it? I would like to get the content of the .txt file in a global variable.

This is what i got right now:

```
async function loadFileAndPrintToConsole(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.text();
    //console.log(data);
    document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    setTestVariable(err);
  }
  getAlert();
}

function getVariable(){
  txtVariable = document. getElementById("debug1").innerHTML;
}
```

Can this be achieved any simpler?

Comment: Instead of `document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = data;` you can write `window.debug1 = data`. It's how we set a global variable.

Comment: thank you @pooria This was the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = data; you can write window.debug1 = data. It's how we set a global variable.

Thank you to @pooria